# How to add active contours to bounding box in live video

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-cvst

Here is developed model for face detection using 'VIOLA AND JOHNES ALGORITHM' and 'CAMShift'. It is using a bounding box to track and detect face. I want to add active contours / dynamic active contours to get the exact shape of the face in the live video. It should only catch the contours of the face not its features. How do I add the active contours within the live video in matlab?

```
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

%Get the input device using image acquisition toolbox,resolution = 640x480 to improve performance
obj =imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_320x240','ROI', [1 1 320 240]);
set(obj,'ReturnedColorSpace', 'rgb');
figure('menubar','none','tag','webcam');

while (true)
    frame=step(obj);
    bbox=step(faceDetector,frame);

    boxInserter  = insertObjectAnnotation(frame,'rectangle',bbox, 'Face Detected');

    imshow(boxInserter,'border','tight');

    f=findobj('tag','webcam');

    if (isempty(f));
        [hueChannel,~,~] = rgb2hsv(frame);

% Display the Hue Channel data and draw the bounding box around the face.
figure, imshow(hueChannel), title('Hue channel data');

rectangle('Position',bbox,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',1, 'Face Detected')
hold off
noseDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose');
faceImage    = imcrop(frame,bbox);
imshow(faceImage)  
noseBBox     = step(noseDetector,faceImage);

noseBBox(1:1) = noseBBox(1:1) + bbox(1:1);
videoInfo    = info(obj);
ROI=get(obj,'ROI');
VideoSize = [ROI(3) ROI(4)];

videoPlayer  = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',[300 300 VideoSize+30]);
tracker = vision.HistogramBasedTracker;
initializeObject(tracker, hueChannel, bbox);

while (1)

% Extract the next video frame
    frame = step(obj);
% RGB -> HSV
    [hueChannel,~,~] = rgb2hsv(frame);

    % Track using the Hue channel data
    bbox = step(tracker, hueChannel);

    % Insert a bounding box around the object being tracked

    %Insert text coordinates

    % Display the annotated video frame using the video player object
    step(videoPlayer);
    pause (.2)
end

% Release resources
release(obj);
release(videoPlayer);

        close(gcf)

        break
    end
    pause(0.05)
end
release(obj)
```

Comment: sorry if I asked on wrong forum, maybe I should ask it on 'Meta Stack Overflow'? Just tell me do not 'vote down' me for it, if needed I will move this question there.

Comment: I think your question belongs here; quite interesting as well!

Comment: What should a question about programming do on Meta SO? The question itself is valid although it could need editing because adding contours is totally independent of what you actually display (a face, a square, something else). So one would need to present a better example.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `activecontour` function in the Image Processing Toolbox. You can crop the bounding box containing the face, and try use `activecontour` to find the exact shape of the face.

Comment: It still needs initial mask location. With constantly changing frames and not fixed bounding box this tutorial will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach but it might help to get exact shape of the face based on facial landmarks. http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/clandmark/